# Automating the Highcharts by Java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium

I am automating the High charts graph using java script. As this not possible in selenium.
URL is https://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-basic

I have identified that, this class contains the values i need to add. ie tspan[2]

i found that this dom elements return me 5 as length

```
document.getElementsByClassName("highcharts-label highcharts-data-label highcharts-data-label-color-0")

<g class="highcharts-data-labels highcharts-series-0 highcharts-bar-series highcharts-color-0 highcharts-tracker " transform="translate(68,73) scale(1 1)" opacity="1">
<g class="highcharts-label highcharts-data-label highcharts-data-label-color-0 " transform="translate(17,2)" opacity="0" visibility="hidden">
<text x="5" style="font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;color:#000000;fill:#000000;" y="16">
<tspan class="highcharts-text-outline" x="5" y="16" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2px" stroke-linejoin="round">107</tspan>
<tspan x="5" y="16">107</tspan>
</text>
</g>
<g class="highcharts-label highcharts-data-label highcharts-data-label-color-0 " transform="translate(5,54)">
<text x="5" style="font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;color:#000000;fill:#000000;" y="16">
<tspan class="highcharts-text-outline" x="5" y="16" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2px" stroke-linejoin="round" style="">31</tspan>
<tspan x="5" y="16">31</tspan>
</text>
</g>
<g class="highcharts-label highcharts-data-label highcharts-data-label-color-0 " transform="translate(102,106)">
<text x="5" style="font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;color:#000000;fill:#000000;" y="16">
<tspan class="highcharts-text-outline" x="5" y="16" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2px" stroke-linejoin="round">635</tspan>
<tspan x="5" y="16">635</tspan>
</text>
</g>
<g class="highcharts-label highcharts-data-label highcharts-data-label-color-0 " transform="translate(33,158)">
<text x="5" style="font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;color:#000000;fill:#000000;" y="16">
<tspan class="highcharts-text-outline" x="5" y="16" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2px" stroke-linejoin="round">203</tspan>
<tspan x="5" y="16">203</tspan>
</text>
</g>
<g class="highcharts-label highcharts-data-label highcharts-data-label-color-0 " transform="translate(0,211)">
<text x="5" style="font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;color:#000000;fill:#000000;" y="16">
<tspan class="highcharts-text-outline" x="5" y="16" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2px" stroke-linejoin="round">2</tspan>
<tspan x="5" y="16">2</tspan>
</text>
</g>
</g>
```

similarly i have different classes brown and green colors.
HTML is

```
<g class="highcharts-data-labels highcharts-series-1 highcharts-bar-series highcharts-color-1 highcharts-tracker " transform="translate(68,73) scale(1 1)" opacity="1">
<g class="highcharts-label highcharts-data-label highcharts-data-label-color-1 " transform="translate(21,12)">
<text x="5" style="font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;color:#000000;fill:#000000;" y="16">
<tspan class="highcharts-text-outline" x="5" y="16" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2px" stroke-linejoin="round">133</tspan>
<tspan x="5" y="16">133</tspan>
</text>
</g>
<g class="highcharts-label highcharts-data-label highcharts-data-label-color-1 " transform="translate(25,64)">
<text x="5" style="font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;color:#000000;fill:#000000;" y="16">
<tspan class="highcharts-text-outline" x="5" y="16" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2px" stroke-linejoin="round">156</tspan>
<tspan x="5" y="16">156</tspan>
</text>
</g>
<g class="highcharts-label highcharts-data-label highcharts-data-label-color-1 " transform="translate(152,117)">
<text x="5" style="font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;color:#000000;fill:#000000;" y="16">
<tspan class="highcharts-text-outline" x="5" y="16" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2px" stroke-linejoin="round">947</tspan>
<tspan x="5" y="16">947</tspan>
</text>
</g>
<g class="highcharts-label highcharts-data-label highcharts-data-label-color-1 " transform="translate(65,169)">
<text x="5" style="font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;color:#000000;fill:#000000;" y="16">
<tspan class="highcharts-text-outline" x="5" y="16" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2px" stroke-linejoin="round">408</tspan>
<tspan x="5" y="16">408</tspan>
</text>
</g>
<g class="highcharts-label highcharts-data-label highcharts-data-label-color-1 " transform="translate(1,221)" opacity="0" visibility="hidden">
<text x="5" style="font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;color:#000000;fill:#000000;" y="16">
<tspan class="highcharts-text-outline" x="5" y="16" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2px" stroke-linejoin="round">6</tspan>
<tspan x="5" y="16">6</tspan>
</text>
</g>
</g>
```

How do i do traversing to the child elements by using parent class ?
and Is there a way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following

```
document.getElementsByClassName("highcharts-label highcharts-data-label highcharts-data-label-color-0")[0].getElementsByTagName("tspan")[1]
```

Comment: Hi, i used the element along with textContent. But its returning only one element of DOM.
document.getElementsByClassName("highcharts-label highcharts-data-label highcharts-data-label-color-0")[1].getElementsByTagName("tspan")[1].textContent

When i replaced the class index with another index value. Its giving second value of the list.

Comment: you can try with loops to traverse all elements

Comment: Hi Murthi, Please check this -
var outerClass = document.getElementsByClassName("highcharts-label highcharts-data-label highcharts-data-label-color-0");
var innerClass = document.getElementsByTagName("tspan")[2];
for (var i = 0; i < outerClass.length; i += 1) {
     innerClass.textContent+= outerClass[i];
    }
//// Output :
I am getting - 
"Source: [object SVGGElement][object SVGGElement][object SVGGElement][object SVGGElement][object SVGGElement]"

Comment: try this var outerClass = document.getElementsByClassName("highcharts-label highcharts-data-label highcharts-data-label-color-0");
var valArry=[];
for (var i = 0; i < outerClass.length; i += 1)
{ 
  valArry.push(outerClass[i].getElementsByTagName('tspan')[1].innerHTML);
}

valArry;

Comment: I tried it. Get an illegal character exception. The site is open https://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-basic. You can have a look.

Thank-you for your help.

Comment: i have tried it using same site. it is working fine.